# Subdivison Surface Modifier / UV islands boundary Problem

Tags: uv

I have some subdivision + UV boundary problem
My English is poor. So I prepare image
[image]

As  you see the picture
The Blender's result of UV islands boundaries are different with other DCC, after subdivision
I think my blender "smooth, keep corners" option didn't work properly
I need the same Result, Like Maya and 3Ds Max

I use blender for modeling and Texture painting
But I cannot do texture paint with This kind of UV islands boundary result to export to other DCC
Please!! Help me!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

to get the same result as Maya/3DS Max, follow these steps:

1. apply SubSurf modifier with **Sharp** option instead of **Smooth, keep corners**

   [image: first-step]
2. your uv layout will be changed into this (notice the sharp borders)

   [image: second-step]
3. select uv's borders and pin them (press **P** key), so those vertices will keep the position in the uv-space (pinned vertices are red)

   [image: third-step]
4. select all vertices (in the uv editor) and press **U** to update all the other vertices - you should get this result

   [image: fourth-step]

Comment: Oh, so this is how you use the sharp option :). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!!      Usally I painted Low-polyon with Ctrl+1 or Ctrl+2 subdivision surface      As you know, Painted with Ctrl+2 and then turn the model Ctrl+0         There are problems with UV islands boundary       opposite way, Painted with Ctrl+0 and then turn the model Ctrl+2     There are also problems with UV islands boundary       I think I need more radical(?) solution   So kind of Subdivision Add-on or Blender subdivision option       But. this is really cool solution.      Thanks sir!!