# Blender Subdivision UV border problem

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

I want to make character animation in blender.

and, I also want to rendering character object with Ctrl+0, Ctrl+1... case by case

but, I have a problem with UV border.

[image]

you can see my problem in the image.

I think the problem came from Subdivision uv border treatment.

Blender's subdivision uv is like 'Pin Corners' in Maya. but I need like 'Pin Borders' in Maya

Is there any function in Blender or any addon?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi. How is this different from your [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179664/subdivison-surface-modifier-uv-islands-boundary-problem)?

Comment: hi. thanks for your asking!!

g.garone solution is great.
but, g.garone's solution needs "apply" 'subdivision surface. 
and edit UV after "apply" subdivision surface.

My question is different.
If I have character and rigging ( Crtl+0 mesh state) is done. 
After animating, I will have to render the character.

Comment: If my character is far from camera. I'll render the character with Ctrl+0 state.
but, My character is very close. i should render the character with Ctrl+2 state above..

Mesh' Subdivision surface level should be switchable with Scene condition.
But, I cannot find the solution the UV Border problem.

If I paint object wit Citl+0. I have a border seam with Ctrl+1,..
I can't do the g.garone's solution for every scenes.

If you use Maya, Max, or other DCC. you know what I want.

My english is poor. but i hope to understand my question.

Thanks!!